# Which statistics to apply (dependent is ordinal and independent is categorical)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, categorical-data, ordinal-data

I have my data in a CSV file for a survey response. Gender is an umordered factor with two levels (Male and Female) and Rating is an ordinal factor (1-5)

```
Gender Rating
M      1
M      2
F      5
M      4
F      3
```

and so on
I want to find out if there is a statistically significant difference in the ratings between Males and Females for the survey.

I am trying to figure out what type of test to use when my dependent variable is multilevel ordinal data and the independent variable is categorical.

Any help here with some sample code is appreciated.

From what I have read, wilcoxon.test seems to be the way, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Mann-Whitney U test is a possibility if you want non-parametric test. You may want to adjust for tie-corrections. Chi-square test of independent (you have two variables) is another possibility.

If you want to examine the parametric methods, you may want to take a look at the following article:

> [Analyzing and Interpreting Data From Likert-Type Scales](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3886444)

Another link:

> https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_statistical_analysis_should_I_use_for_Likert-Scale_data